# Why doesn't WebSecurity.Logout *immediately* update IPrincipal.User to null user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, forms-authentication

*First of all it's important to note that in my application if you log out your session is still valid and you don't just get redirected back to a login page, but stay on the same page.*

With that said - whichever of these two ways I use to sign out in an MVC application

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
WebSecurity.Logout()
```

the effect is the same and neither of the following properties changes to reflect the logout if I immediately access them :

```
User.Identity.Name
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity
```

Now - If I do a Redirect, or just reload the page then obviously these properties are updated to a null user. They just don't immediately meaning that `User.Identity.Name` represents a user that just logged out.

This is a problem because I want to generate text of the form `You are logged in as XXX` after login/logout - and this may be in an AJAX situation where a redirect isn't possible.

I'm curious if there's any way to trigger the `IPrincipal` to reset itself after a logout (or login).

I assume people normally just `Redirect()` after a `Logout()` call so this is never an issue, but in an AJAX situation this is not always practical.

My current solution is to abstract the Identity in my own wrapper, and so once I'm logged out I can just update that. I'm just a little concerned that this could have some obscure side effects especially if somebody accesses `IPrincipal` directly adn not through the wrapper.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem here? Why would any more code run after you've triggered the logout using ajax? The next action would be a new request.

Comment: @matt that's the whole point. I don't want a 'next action' if by that you mean a Redirect(). It shouldn't be necessary - the auth cookie will still be cleared provided the 'more code' doesn't result in a 500 error. In fact this 'more code' is trivial and just returns some JSON which contains the 'current user', but User.Identity returns the 'old' user. I guess ultimately I don't see any technical reason why It isn't immediately cleared. My 'wrapper' works just fine but I'm just trying to understand if there's a reason why it isn't cleared or if its an oversight.

Comment: Also the same is true when you login - WebSecurity.CurrentUsername isn't updated and neither is IPrincipal. I have a shopping cart page with an optional login on the page. I need to track if e login was successful instead of just relying on WebSecurity.CurrentUsername

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a core limitation of the ASP.NET event pipeline as it relates to forms authentication. This also makes it vulnerable to replay attacks, as described in [KB article 900111](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/900111). In that article, they reference one solution to use a membership provider that stores some server-side information about the logged on user.

Membership provider seems very similar to the approach you are thinking of taking, and I wonder if you should consider using one of the built-in membership providers, or writing your custom code as a membership provider. This should address some of the concern about people not understanding the approach and calling the IPrincipal directly.

Your "logout but stay on the same page" brings the issue a little more to the fore, but ultimately you're just uncovering the same fundamental replay issue that everyone has with ASP.NET (but not everyone solves it).

[This related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117930/preventing-cookie-replay-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc) may also be helpful.