# Why Doesn't Asp.Net Session.Clear() Work On Close Tab When I See It Run?

Tags: asp.net, security, session, webforms

I have been attempting to get a clean break from a session when a tab is closed for a workplace system used by supervisors and others. I am successful when the person logs out - all is cleared. However, when a tab is closed, it can be reopened at will as if session.clear() was never called.

I am using this javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "default.aspx/EndSession",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) { }
 });
```

to call this web method:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string EndSession()
{
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
   HttpContext.Current.User = null;
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
   return "";
}
```

I set a breakpoint and watch the code execute as I step through it and it returns. The tab closes, and then I right-click and select "reopen closed tab" and the page comes back and the session is still active.

I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921941/close-kill-the-session-when-the-browser-or-tab-is-closed) ppl saying this is not possible, but don't understand why, since the code is running on the server - I'm watching it run, and the session is not cleared. I would have thought this was the point of an explicit call to "Session.Clear()" and "Session.Abandon()". The same code in the logout Page_Load works great.

Why? What am I missing? Is the session clear being thrown out after running because the tab is closed?

Thanks!

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14913314/151212). IMO, the only real solution is to store something server-side and not depend only on session cookie.

Comment: Heading this way now. There is a possibility that the session will be open in more than one tab, so there is the added complexity of that, but for now I am going to start with the suggestions you pointed to. Thanks for the info - I will post back when I have success (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `Session.RemoveAll();` and `redirect` to another page too?

```
public static string EndSession()
{
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
   HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAll();
   HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", true);
   HttpContext.Current.User = null;
   FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
   return "";
}
```

In addition to code above add on Page_Load:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoServerCaching();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

I am not 100% sure of it will work, I thought to write it hopefully it can be of some help.

Comment: Added the line you suggested. I had the cache stuff in there before and just now tried the redirect - I had already tried it from javascript, and it was ignored (probably by design). No luck from codebehind either. So the comments in the OP are probably my best option.