# Where is the ClaimsIdentity information stored after calling AuthenticationManager.SignIn() using CookieAuthenticationProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, claims-based-identity, asp.net-authorization

We are using the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationProvider` in an ASP.Net MVC web application.

The 'sign in' code uses a custom class that keeps track of authorization info (`userRights` in the example below). The code looks like this:

```
string auth = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRights);
ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, auth),
}, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

AuthenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
```

My concern is that this information may be stored inside the authentication cookie and sent to the client where it could potentially be manipulated or changed.

The source code does a great job of concealing what happens. In VisualStudio "Go to implementation" states that it cannot find any implementation of `IAuthenticationManager.SignIn` and the source code of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationProvider` just shows a bunch of `Action` delegates which I cannot debug since I have no symbols.

Another concern is [Cookie replay attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117930/preventing-cookie-replay-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc). I am thinking of solving both potential problems by using the session store like this:

```
Session.Add("AuthorizationDecision", userRights);
```

and on logoff:

```
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
AuthenticationManager.SignOut();
```

This way I can be sure that the information is not going to the client and cannot be manipulated there. But I may be overlooking something or my original concern may have no grounds (which I cannot check due to obscure code). Our team is concerned that "the session is not made for authorization and may not be encrypted or as safe as using Claims" It would be great if you experts could share your thoughts or relieve my concerns by explaining where the claims are stored.

-- EDIT --

I went ahead and removed the authorization from the authentication claims (since no one seems to know where the info is persisted). It can be cached in the session but the session has a totally independent life span compared to the cookie, so null checking is needed, and a check on `ClaimsIdentity.IsAuthenticated` is also needed when the session is not null.

Answer (score 3):

have had the same question regarding where the claims data is stored. regarding your concern:

> My concern is that this information may be stored inside the authentication cookie and sent to the client where it could potentially be manipulated or changed.

The cookies are encrypted and signed so that the data can't be neither viewed nor tampered on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, you don't explicitly say that the `userRights` are stored in the cookie, but if they are, they are safe... Well, I guess there still are enough reasons to store them somewhere server-side. For example, when rights are changed the cache can be updated without the user needing to log out and in again. But your point does alleviate the concern of client-manipulation.